# Store name appears twice in meta titles while searching in Google?

Tags: magento, title, google-search

In Google, while searching my (Magento) site, the `meta title` appears twice. I am new to Magento, and don't know why it's appearing twice.

[image]

Comment: Don't feel obligated to accept defacing edits, Sri.

Comment: @Sri We can't help you without your code/configuration.  A simple picture isn't going to do us any good.

Comment: @Daedalus I thought there is no chance for code mistake because while checking page source the meta keys didn't repeat twice so I think its configuring mistake so only I just put the screen shot....

Comment: @Sri .. Interesting.  SEO isn't my forte unfortunately.  Have you attempted to contact Google?  Also, is this for all search engines?

Comment: @Deadalus I tried all the sides but still can't find the correct solution for this so could you give me your ideas how it could be done could you please explain in a breif manner it would be very very helpful .

Comment: @Sri I did.  I asked if you attempted to contact Google regarding this, but if by 'sides' you mean 'sites', then for the moment, I'm stumped.

Comment: @Daedalus Here i mention sides means I tried all direction for this question but i can't find the solution that only i have mentioned and I didn't contact google regarding this If there any other way that you can help us please let me know?

Comment: @Sri Then my question stands: Are you experiencing this in search engines aside from Google?  If not, have you tried contacting Google regarding it?

Comment: What does doing a View Source for your pages referred to by the SERP entries with the duplicates show? Sounds like a Magento misconfiguration.

Comment: @Fiasco Labs I dont know where to change in magento configuration for this task if you know please explain your ideas it will be very helpful to me...

Comment: In general, this kind of problem is just a SEO plugin configuration problem.

Comment: @ZIstoloen in the plugin what is the problem I cant find where exactly the problem is so could you please explain where exactly the problem will occur in the plugin could you please explain in a detaliled manner

Comment: @Sri: in general, you define a title with your CMS and your SEO plugin also defines a title. If you put the same title for both, it can generating this kind of problem.

Comment: @Zistolen I check with that in there it have mentioned only one times but in Google itself it displaying twice...

Comment: Asking how Google displays/ranks a site is off topic

Comment: @random why you are saying that its an off topic may I know the reason...

Comment: There is no programming involved here, just asking how a search engine chooses to display results. This is better on [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) maybe

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming question.